# Navigating to next hunk in a patch file using VIM

Tags: vim, patch

Some of us are familiar with `patch` failures like `"Hunk #11 FAILED at 958."` -- is there a command in VIM that allows me to go to, say, 11th hunk ... without having to manually count it? Even a shortcut to go to the *next* patch would useful.

Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method to move between patch hunks is first to search for the beginning of the patch marker

- in a unified diff

  `/^@@`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- in a context diff

  `/^\*\{15}`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

and then to move to the next hunk by repeating the search with

<kbd>n</kbd> (or multiple hunks at a time, e.g. `3`<kbd>n</kbd>)

To move backwards by hunks use

<kbd>N</kbd> (or e.g. `4`<kbd>N</kbd>)

---

If you know all the hunk numbers you need to see, e.g. the 11<sup>th</sup> and 24<sup>th</sup> hunk, you can first use the amount prefix search Hugh suggested: `11/^@@`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and after that move to 24<sup>th</sup> hunk either by calculating always from the top: `gg24`<kbd>n</kbd> or by direct forward advance: `13`<kbd>n</kbd> (hunk #24 is 13 hunks ahead from the 11<sup>th</sup>).

Comment: Thanks to both Hugh and Jawa for the `@@` search trick. And `gg24n` is something new for me, and that completes the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the first line of a patch file in command mode*, you can go to the 11th hunk:-

- in a context diff:

  `11/^\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- in a unified diff:

  `11/^@@`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

* and by command mode, I mean what the help calls normal mode - that is, not insert mode, and not command-line mode (<kbd>:</kbd>)